# Shadow camera around specified area

Tags: three.js

Is there any solution how to make shadow camera (it's box boundaries) from directional light follow the main camera in order to cast shadows only to a specified area around the camera but not to the whole scene?

Comment: I would also like to know this as having the same trouble myself (having efficient shadows in a large scene with small objects).